# how to insert unique code to a table through loop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to insert words into a table. words need to be unique.

Like:

```
  AAAAA
  AAAAB
  AAAAC

  .....
  .....
  .....

  ZZZZZ
```

Is there any simple way to implement this?

Comment: Please show what you have attempted so far. Thanks!

Comment: btw, why do you want to do this ?

Comment: I am only going to help if you respond. Can you type ?

Comment: i need unique code that have 5 characters

Comment: @user1751909 - Yes, that is obvious. But why do you want to do that in SQL server ?

Comment: i would like to make a script for that

Comment: @user1751909 - !!! Why do you need such a script in SQL ? It can be done, but programming lang would be better.

Comment: ok. would you give any code snippet of that

Comment: @user1751909 - so, you just want to do nothing while everyone else  does the hard work for you ? answer my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare     @a  int = 65,
      @b  int =  90,
      @a1  int = 65,
      @b1  int = 90,
      @a2  int = 65,
      @b2  int = 90

    while(@a<=@b)
    begin
    set @a1 = 65
    while(@a1<=@b1)
    begin
    set @a2 = 65
    while(@a2<=@b2)
    begin
    print char(@a) + char(@a1) +char(@a2)
    set @a2 = @a2+1
    end
    set @a1 = @a1+1
    end
    set @a = @a+1
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the complete code. I will purposely not give you the whole thing. Use the code below to develop the whole thing YOURSELF -

```
select ASCII('A') as Ano
select ASCII('Z') as Zno

declare @count int = 1
while(@count <= 26)
    begin
    print @count
    set @count = @count + 1
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Not Exact Answer.

but will give you some idea with this

```
;WITH Alphabet AS 
(
    SELECT CHAR(65) AS Letter,CHAR(65) AS LetterNew, 65 AS Code
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CHAR(Code + 1),CHAR(Code),  Code + 1
    FROM Alphabet
    WHERE Code < 90
) 

SELECT Letter+Letter+Letter+Letter+LetterNew FROM Alphabet
UNION
SELECT Letter+Letter+Letter+LetterNew+Letter FROM Alphabet
UNION
SELECT Letter+Letter+LetterNew+Letter+Letter FROM Alphabet
UNION
SELECT Letter+LetterNew+Letter+Letter+Letter FROM Alphabet
UNION
SELECT LetterNew+Letter+Letter+Letter+Letter FROM Alphabet
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/16083)**

Comment: so, how much does one have to edit this to get the desired number of rows, i.e 26^6 ?